# Getting Swedish letters to work in LaTex

Tags: listings, babel, languages, input-encodings, listingsutf8

**Problem:**

- **Issue 1 (solved):** The Swedish letters ÅÄÖ/åäö do not print out correctly when used with `listings` package.
- **Issue 2:** How can it be solved so that the Swedish letters also get orange color like the rest of the letters?
- **Issue 3:** How can it be solved to get the PHP-line (line 10) to be on the same line as line 9?

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Latex template for coding in PHP
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Definition of colors for code highlight
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{editorLightGray}{cmyk}{0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1}
\definecolor{editorGray}{cmyk}{0.6, 0.55, 0.55, 0.2}
\definecolor{editorPurple}{cmyk}{0.4,0.9,0,0}
\definecolor{editorWhite}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorBlack}{cmyk}{1, 1, 1, 1}
\definecolor{editorOrange}{cmyk}{0, 0.65, 1, 0}
\definecolor{editorBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.5, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorPink}{cmyk}{0, 1, 0, 0}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Defining parameters/keywords for PHP
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}{
  language=html,
  sensitive=true,
  tagstyle=\color{editorBlue},
  markfirstintag=true,
  morecomment=[s]{<!-}{-->},
  alsoletter={!},
  keywords={},
  %alsoletter={<>=-+},
  %tag=[s],
}

\lstdefinelanguage{PHP}{
        morestring=[s]{'}{'},
        morestring=[b]",
        morecomment=[l]{//},
        sensitive=true,
        alsoletter={::},
        keywords=[1]{require_once, try, new, catch, die, echo, sprintf},
        keywords=[2]{setAttribute, getMessage, PDO, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION},
        keywords=[3]{PDOException, php},
        keywords=[4]{athletics}
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Design of listings for PHP
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\lstset{%
    % Basic design
    backgroundcolor=\color{editorWhite},
    basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily},   
    frame=l,
    % Line numbers
    xleftmargin={20pt},
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    firstnumber=1,
    numberfirstline=true,
    % Code design
    identifierstyle=\color{editorOrange},
    keywordstyle=[1]\color{editorPink}\bfseries,
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{editorBlue}\bfseries,
    keywordstyle=[3]\color{editorBlack}\bfseries,
    keywordstyle=[4]\color{editorBlue}\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\color{editorGray}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{editorPurple},
    % Code
    language=php,
    alsodigit={.:},
    tabsize=2,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=false,
    % Support for German umlauts
    literate=%
    {Ö}{{\"O}}1
    {Ä}{{\"A}}1
    {Å}{{\AA{}}}1
    {Ü}{{\"U}}1
    {ß}{{\ss}}1
    {ü}{{\"u}}1
    {ö}{{\"o}}1
    {ä}{{\"a}}1
    {å}{{\aa{}}}1
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Formatted code in document
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML5,numbers=left,firstnumber=1]
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Utskrift av datum</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Skriver ut årtal, månad och dag enligt YYYY-MM-DD -->
    <p>Dagens datum är
\end{lstlisting}
\vspace*{-12pt}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=PHP,numbers=left,firstnumber=last]
<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>
\end{lstlisting}
\vspace*{-12pt}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML5,numbers=left,firstnumber=last]
  </p>
  </body>
</html>
\end{lstlisting}
\vspace*{-12pt}
\end{document}
```

The errors indicate issues with the Swedish letters. I used `literate` for the `listings` package to solve this issue but without success.

**Current outcome:**

[image]

**Desired outcome:**

The letter `ä` to be the same color as the rest (i.e. orange) and the PHP-code to be on the same line as the `<p>` element.

Comment: Do you see `å` among the characters you've given in `literate`? Other than that, is using `xelatex` or `lualatex` an option? If I remove `inputenc` and add `\usepackage{fontspec}` before compiling with either of those, it just works. Also without `literate`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. The issue is with `ä` and not with `å`. But thanks for pointing it out. I will update the code and try your other recommendations.

Comment: @daleif Image added.

Comment: As for the `php` line. You cannot get it up there with the construction you are using. The line has ended at that point.

Comment: @daleif That's fine. I can just leave it as it is. Any ideas for making the letter `ä` orange?

Comment: Not really, there are other `listings` experts around. This is one of the reasons why I always recommend documenting in English. Much less problems. Also I only think the following tags are relevant: `listings`, `utf8`, `color`

Answer (score 3):

## Using a Unicode-aware engine

If changing engine to either XeTeX or LuaTeX is an option, then you can remove the `literate` stuff from the `\lstset`, remove `inputenc` and add `fontspec`. With those modifications it just works.

Note that in the code below I set `belowskip` and `aboveskip` to `0pt` where necessary to remove the gap between the different `listings`, rather than using `\vspace{-12pt}`.

[image]

```
% !TeX program = xelatex

\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ragged2e}


% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Definition of colors for code highlight
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{editorLightGray}{cmyk}{0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1}
\definecolor{editorGray}{cmyk}{0.6, 0.55, 0.55, 0.2}
\definecolor{editorPurple}{cmyk}{0.4,0.9,0,0}
\definecolor{editorWhite}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorBlack}{cmyk}{1, 1, 1, 1}
\definecolor{editorOrange}{cmyk}{0, 0.65, 1, 0}
\definecolor{editorBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.5, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorPink}{cmyk}{0, 1, 0, 0}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Defining parameters/keywords for PHP
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}{
  language=html,
  sensitive=true,
  tagstyle=\color{editorBlue},
  markfirstintag=true,
  morecomment=[s]{<!-}{-->},
  alsoletter={!},
  keywords={},
  %alsoletter={<>=-+},
  %tag=[s],
}

\lstdefinelanguage{PHP}{
        morestring=[s]{'}{'},
        morestring=[b]",
        morecomment=[l]{//},
        sensitive=true,
        alsoletter={::},
        keywords=[1]{require_once, try, new, catch, die, echo, sprintf},
        keywords=[2]{setAttribute, getMessage, PDO, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION},
        keywords=[3]{PDOException, php},
        keywords=[4]{athletics}
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Design of listings for PHP
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\lstset{%
    % Basic design
    backgroundcolor=\color{editorWhite},
    basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily},   
    frame=l,
    % Line numbers
    xleftmargin={20pt},
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    firstnumber=1,
    numberfirstline=true,
    % Code design
    identifierstyle=\color{editorOrange},
    keywordstyle=[1]\color{editorPink}\bfseries,
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{editorBlue}\bfseries,
    keywordstyle=[3]\color{editorBlack}\bfseries,
    keywordstyle=[4]\color{editorBlue}\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\color{editorGray}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{editorPurple},
    % Code
    language=php,
    alsodigit={.:},
    tabsize=2,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=false,
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Formatted code in document
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML5,numbers=left,firstnumber=1,belowskip=0pt]
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Utskrift av datum</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Skriver ut årtal, månad och dag enligt YYYY-MM-DD -->
    <p>Dagens datum är
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=PHP,numbers=left,firstnumber=last,belowskip=0pt,aboveskip=0pt]
<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>
\end{lstlisting}%
\begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML5,numbers=left,firstnumber=last,aboveskip=0pt]
  </p>
  </body>
</html>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

## Using `pdflatex`

While the following works with `pdflatex` it is limited. This is taken more or less directly from section 9 of the `listings` manual. The `literate` stuff is again removed, and two lines are added to `\lstset`:

```
escapeinside=`',
escapebegin={\color{editorGray}}
```

The comments with the Scandinavian characters are typed between `` ` `` and `'`. `escapeinside` means that between the two characters specified, `listings` jumps back to 'normal' LaTeX mode. The `escapebegin` line means that the `\color` specification will be added to the start of each escaped part, and because LaTeX renders this as usual, the text is coloured.

You see where the limitation lies -- as used here all such text blocks will have the same colour. If you only have such characters in comments, then it's no problem. If you have them elsewhere, you will have to add an extra `\color{..}` at the start of every escaped sequence that should have a different colour, as with `\color{editorOrange}` in this case. Hence it means a lot of extra fiddling.

(Note that I am by no means an expert when it comes to `listings`, so there may well be better ways of doing this.)

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex

\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Definition of colors for code highlight
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\definecolor{editorLightGray}{cmyk}{0.05, 0.05, 0.05, 0.1}
\definecolor{editorGray}{cmyk}{0.6, 0.55, 0.55, 0.2}
\definecolor{editorPurple}{cmyk}{0.4,0.9,0,0}
\definecolor{editorWhite}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorBlack}{cmyk}{1, 1, 1, 1}
\definecolor{editorOrange}{cmyk}{0, 0.65, 1, 0}
\definecolor{editorBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.5, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorPink}{cmyk}{0, 1, 0, 0}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Defining parameters/keywords for PHP
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}{
  language=html,
  sensitive=true,
  tagstyle=\color{editorBlue},
  markfirstintag=true,
  morecomment=[s]{<!-}{-->},
  alsoletter={!},
  keywords={},
  %alsoletter={<>=-+},
  %tag=[s],
}

\lstdefinelanguage{PHP}{
        morestring=[s]{'}{'},
        morestring=[b]",
        morecomment=[l]{//},
        sensitive=true,
        alsoletter={::},
        keywords=[1]{require_once, try, new, catch, die, echo, sprintf},
        keywords=[2]{setAttribute, getMessage, PDO, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION},
        keywords=[3]{PDOException, php},
        keywords=[4]{athletics}
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Design of listings for PHP
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\lstset{%
    % Basic design
    backgroundcolor=\color{editorWhite},
    basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily},   
    frame=l,
    % Line numbers
    xleftmargin={20pt},
    numbers=left,
    stepnumber=1,
    firstnumber=1,
    numberfirstline=true,
    % Code design
    identifierstyle=\color{editorOrange},
    keywordstyle=[1]\color{editorPink}\bfseries,
    keywordstyle=[2]\color{editorBlue}\bfseries,
    keywordstyle=[3]\color{editorBlack}\bfseries,
    keywordstyle=[4]\color{editorBlue}\bfseries,
    commentstyle=\color{editorGray}\ttfamily,
    stringstyle=\color{editorPurple},
    % Code
    language=php,
    alsodigit={.:},
    tabsize=2,
    showtabs=false,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=true,
    breaklines=false,
    escapeinside=`',
    escapebegin={\color{editorGray}}
}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Formatted code in document
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML5,numbers=left,firstnumber=1,belowskip=0pt]
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Utskrift av datum</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- `Skriver ut årtal, månad och dag enligt YYYY-MM-DD' -->
    <p>`\color{editorOrange}Dagens datum är'
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=PHP,numbers=left,firstnumber=last,belowskip=0pt,aboveskip=0pt]
<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>
\end{lstlisting}%
\begin{lstlisting}[language=HTML5,numbers=left,firstnumber=last,aboveskip=0pt]
  </p>
  </body>
</html>
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to draft this. I tried to switch compiler and too many errors occurred. I could figure out some of them and others were to complicated. Is there a way to do this with `pdflatex`?

Comment: @kexxcream If I knew, I would have posted that. If this answer is worthless for you I can always delete it.

Comment: No, keep it. I will talk to my editor to see if we can't  apply this strategy on the next project.

Comment: @kexxcream A glance at the manual led me to one way of doing it, though not a very convenient one. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

This was the solution I came up with for the first part of the question. Put the following line in the header:

```
\usepackage{inconsolata} % Swedish encoding in lstlisting
```

and then where you want the code listing put the code below.

```
\lstset{
  language=bash, % Switch code language ... bash is the default
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  numberstyle=\tiny,
  numbers=left,
  backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},
  frame=single,
  tabsize=2,
  rulecolor=\color{black!30},
  title=\lstname,
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  framextopmargin=2pt,
  framexbottommargin=2pt,
  inputencoding=utf8,
  extendedchars=true,
  % Support for Swedish, German and Portuguese umlauts
  literate=%
  {Ö}{{\"O}}1
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1
  {Å}{{\AA{}}}1
  {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {ö}{{\"o}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1
  {å}{{\aa{}}}1
  {á}{{\'a}}1
  {ã}{{\~a}}1
  {é}{{\'e}}1,
}
\lstinputlisting[language=bash]{your_code_file.txt}
```